# Durandal 2.1 entrance transition and static positioning of page-host

Tags: durandal

In Durandal 2.1 starterkit the page-host div is positioned absolute (top: 50px,...) 
I tried to use static positioning in order to have a common footer after page-host.

```
.page-host { padding-top: 50px;}
```

Unfortunately with static positioning the animation is broken  - the padding-top (or margin-top) is added only after animation is complete.
Any suggestion how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two things you could do:

1. [Write your own transition](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Transition.html); or
2. Use the transition from Durandal 2.0.1, which uses javascript to animate rather than CSS animations (as suggested in [Rob's release announcement](http://eisenbergeffect.bluespire.com/durandal-2-1-0-released/)).

The second one is obviously the easiest; you can find the entrance transition from 2.0.1 here:

https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/2.0.1/src/transitions/js/entrance.js

Comment: As suggested I used 2.0.1 - javascript animation. It would be still nice If anybody can fix this for version 2.1